# Add Classpath in Manifest file of jar in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

Below is my gradle script and I need to add the data in MANIFEST.MF of jar file in below format I tried the below method but not able to achieve it. i need it in below way. I am using the gradle 2.3

```
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    jar.doFirst {
          manifest {
                attributes("Manifest-Version": "1.0",
                          "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '))
          }
    }                


    repositories {

         maven { url "http://cmp.tsh.thomson.com:80/artifactory/libs-release" }
         maven { url "http://cmp.tsh.thomson.com:80/artifactory/libs-stage" }
         maven { url "http://cmp.tsh.thomson.com:80/artifactory/libs-snapshot" }
         maven { url "http://cmp.tsh.thomson.com:80/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/" }

    }
    dependencies {
        compile group: 'com.tru.analytics', name: 'analytics-engine-common', version:'4.+'
        compile group: 'com.tru.analytic', name: 'analytics-engine-LicenseVerifier', version:'4.+'
       compile group: 'com.tru.analytics', name: 'MegNativeJNI', version: '4.+', ext: 'so'
       compile group: 'com.tru.analytics', name: 'NativeJNI', version: '4.+', ext: 'so'
        compile(group: 'com.operasolutions', name: 'RiskAnalytics', version:'1.1') {
    exclude(module: 'jyson')
        }
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-expression', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version:'4.0'
        compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'2.4'
        compile group: 'net.sf.supercsv', name: 'super-csv-dozer', version:'2.1.0'
        compile group: 'net.sf.supercsv', name: 'super-csv', version:'2.1.0'
        compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjtools', version:'1.6.2'
        compile group: 'org.python', name: 'jython-standalone', version:'2.5.3'
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version:'1.7.2'
        compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.16'
        compile group: 'com.xhaus', name: 'jyson', version:'1.0.2'
        compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version:'17.0'
        compile group: 'com.jamonapi', name: 'jamon', version:'2.4'
        compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version:'1.1.1'
        compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version:'1.1.1'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.6'
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.mojo', name: 'properties-maven-plugin', version:'1.0-alpha-2'
        compile group: 'args4j', name: 'args4j', version:'2.0.28'
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version:'1.9.5'
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.11'
        testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version:'1.9.5'
    }
    dependencies {
        runtime group: 'com.tru.analytics', name: 'analytics-engine-common', version:'4.+'
        runtime group: 'com.tru.analytics', name: 'analytics-engine-LicenseVerifier', version:'4.+'
       runtime group: 'com.tru.analytics', name: 'MegNativeJNI', version: '4.+', ext: 'so'
      runtime group: 'com.tru.analytics', name: 'NativeJNI', version: '4.+', ext: 'so'
      runtime (group: 'com.operasolutions', name: 'RiskAnalytics', version:'1.1') {
      exclude(module: 'jyson')
        }
        runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-expression', version:'3.2.5.RELEASE'
        runtime group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version:'4.0'
        runtime group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'2.4'
        runtime group: 'net.sf.supercsv', name: 'super-csv-dozer', version:'2.1.0'
        runtime group: 'net.sf.supercsv', name: 'super-csv', version:'2.1.0'
        runtime group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjtools', version:'1.6.2'
        runtime group: 'org.python', name: 'jython-standalone', version:'2.5.3'
        runtime group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version:'1.7.2'
        runtime group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.16'
        runtime group: 'com.xhaus', name: 'jyson', version:'1.0.2'
        runtime group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version:'17.0'
        runtime group: 'com.jamonapi', name: 'jamon', version:'2.4'
        runtime group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version:'1.1.1'
        runtime group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version:'1.1.1'
        runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.6'
        runtime group: 'org.codehaus.mojo', name: 'properties-maven-plugin', version:'1.0-alpha-2'
        runtime group: 'args4j', name: 'args4j', version:'2.0.28'
        runtime group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version:'1.9.5'
       }

    task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
       def dirName = "build/libs/lib"
       file(dirName).mkdirs()
       from configurations.runtime
       into 'build/libs/lib'
    }

    task copylib(type: Copy) {
       dependsOn copyDeps
       def finaldir = file("build/libs/AnalyticsLib-${project.version}-bin")
       file (finaldir).mkdirs()
       from 'build/libs'
       into finaldir
    }

 // adding test report to taskGraph
build.dependsOn copylib
```

Need below result or data in MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: jenkins
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Class-Path: lib/Common-4.0.0-1159.jar lib/uuid-3.2.jar lib/lombok-1.12
 .2.jar lib/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar lib/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar l
 ib/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar lib/LicenseVerifier-4.0.0-1159.jar lib/
 license3j-1.0.4.jar lib/bcpg-jdk16-1.46.jar lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar
  lib/RiskAnalytics-1.1.jar lib/javacsv-2.0.jar lib/spring-context-3.2
 .5.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-core-3.2
 .5.RELEASE.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/spring-aop-3.2.5.REL
 EASE.jar lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar lib/spring-expression-3.2.5.RELEASE.
 jar lib/commons-collections4-4.0.jar lib/commons-io-2.4.jar lib/super
 -csv-dozer-2.1.0.jar lib/dozer-5.4.0.jar lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.
 jar lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar lib/super-
 csv-2.1.0.jar lib/aspectjtools-1.6.2.jar lib/jython-standalone-2.5.3.
 jar lib/gson-1.7.2.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar lib/jyson-1.0.2.jar lib/g
 uava-17.0.jar lib/jamon-2.4.jar lib/logback-classic-1.1.1.jar lib/log
 back-core-1.1.1.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar lib/properties-maven-plug
 in-1.0-alpha-2.jar lib/maven-model-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-plugin-api-2.0
 .6.jar lib/maven-project-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-settings-2.0.6.jar lib/m
 aven-profile-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.6.jar lib/maven
 -repository-metadata-2.0.6.jar lib/wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.jar 
 lib/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar lib/
 plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar lib/classworlds-1.1
 -alpha-2.jar lib/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar lib/args4j-2.0.28.jar lib/jac
 kson-mapper-asl-1.9.5.jar lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.5.jar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably put the `manifest` configuration in `jar` block itself rather than in `doFirst`:

```
jar {
   manifest {
      attributes(
         "Manifest-Version": "1.0",
         "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: can you explain the DSL a bit?  `{ it.getName() }.join(' ') ) }` does what?

Comment: This iterates through the compile dependencies jars and and concatenates the classpath for the MANIFEST.MF. If you want to further customize the classpath string, you can use other operations on the String it.getName(). Example: !it.getName().startsWith('someFilter') ? ("lib/" + it.getName()):("" + it.getName()) - this searches for the specified dependency in some other place...

Comment: I'm getting 
"Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:compile' after it has been resolved."
Gradle Version 4.0. Can someone confirm that?

Comment: This answer is no longer valid after Gradle 4.0.